# How to move cursor to front of line and end of line in terminal in WebStorm?

Tags: webstorm

How to move cursor to front and end of the line in terminal in WebStorm?

I am using iterm2 in iOS. I can set up send hex code on iterm2 as `0x01` as front and `0x05` as end, but how can I do it in WebStorm?

Comment: please see comments in [IDEA-153536](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153536) for some hints (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153536#focus=Comments-27-2851261.0-0, for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @lena's hit I end up to create binding in `~/.bashrc`

```
bind '"\e\e[D": beginning-of-line'
bind '"\e\e[C": end-of-line'
```

and load the ~/.bashrc in terminal app in webstorm
`Webstorm -> Preference -> Tool -> Terminal -> Application Setting -> Shell Path -> /bin/bash --rcfile ~/.bashrc`